# Add download button in Rmd file but do not display a table

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am able to display a table and add a dowmnload link using Data Table DT library e.g.

```
mtcars %>% DT::datatable(extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                        options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                                                       pageLength = 200,
                                                       buttons = list('copy', 'csv', 'excel')))
```

However, I'm not using mtcars I'm using a large csv of training data and the end user would like to be able to download to csv.

The above block, when used with my real data gives a message:

> It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables. You may consider server-side processing: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html

Is there an alternative way where I can provide a download button without attempting to actually show a table (And thus hit memory issues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add a download button to the Rmd document, you could use `shiny::downloadHandler` with `runtime: shiny`. For instance, this Rmd downloads `mtcars` as a .csv file:

````
---
title: "Download .csv"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}

## data (possibly a reactive expression)
myData <- mtcars

## create downloadButton in Rmd document
downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { 
    paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
  }, 
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(myData, file)
  },
  outputArgs = list(label = "Download .csv")
)

```
````

Comment: I added this download button to a Rmd file and it worked. However, when rendering with `rmarkdown::render_site()` and then moving the files generated in _site to a directory on a webserver, the button downloads an html doc instead of a csv. The html doc is just a copy of the html page that is rendered.This doesn't happen when I click 'run' within RStudio. Any ideas?